# Non-UTF8 files (Google CSV file)

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm running into weird encoding issues when handling uploaded files.

I need to accept any sort of text file, and be able to read the contents. Specifically having trouble with files downloaded from a Google Contacts export.

I've done the usual utf8_encode/decode, mb_detect_encoding, etc. Always returns as if the string is UTF-8, and tried many iconv options to try and revert encoding, but unsuccessful.

**test.php**

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

if ($stream = fopen($_FILES['list']['tmp_name'], 'r'))
{
    $string = stream_get_contents($stream);

    fclose($stream);
}

echo substr($string, 0, 50);
var_dump(substr($string, 0, 50));
echo base64_encode(serialize(substr($string, 0, 50)));
```

**Output**

```
��N�a�m�e�,�G�i�v�e�n� �N�a�m�e�,�A�d�d�i�t�i�o�n�
��N�a�m�e�,�G�i�v�e�n� �N�a�m�e�,�A�d�d�i�t�i�o�n�
czo1MDoi//5OAGEAbQBlACwARwBpAHYAZQBuACAATgBhAG0AZQAsAEEAZABkAGkAdABpAG8AbgAiOw==
```

Comment: Encoding errors is too vague. We need an example. Try to post a `base64_encode(serialize($excerpt))` here.

Comment: Updated with example excerpts.

Comment: Where does $string come from? Can you show the code you are using to get it? What encoding are you outputting this in?

Comment: Updated with stream_get_contents. Note: I tried several ways of handling uploaded files and same results occurred. If I copy the contents of the uploaded text file on my computer, then upload a fresh text file with the same contents, is ok. I assume the file encoding of the file itself is non-UTF-8 to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beginning of the string carries the bytes \xFF \xFE which represent the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) for UTF-16 Little Endian. All letters are actually two-byte sequences. Mostly a leading \0 followed by the ASCII character.

Printing them on the console will make the terminal client interpret the UTF-16 sequences correctly. But you need to manually decode it (best via iconv) to make the whole array displayable.

Comment: http://www.codeunit.co.za/2010/03/05/php-convert-a-utf-16-string-to-a-utf-8-string/ provided the code to convert, thanks for noticing the BOM

Comment: @James, have you used this fn() in a large import scenario? I am faced with users uploading large files (10-200mb) for import, and it doesn't seem feasible to run this on EVERY field, and I don't have the luxury to just load it all into memory.

Comment: @Jakub: You could use the [iconv("UTF-16","UTF-8",$str)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function for that. Or if the uploaded files should not be read in, try `system("recode UTF-16..UTF-8 '$filename'");` for a fast in-place conversion on BSD/Linux servers.

Answer (score 0):

When I decoded the base64 piece, I saw a strange mixed string: `s:50:"\xff\xfeN\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00,\x00G\x00i\x00v\x00e\x00n\x00 \x00N\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00,\x00A\x00d\x00d\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00"`. The part after the second `:` is a 2-byte Unicode (UCS2) string enclosed in ASCII `"`, while "s" and "50" are plain ASCII. That `\ff\fe` piece is a byte-order mark of a UCS2 string. This is insane but parseable.

I suppose that you split the input string by `:`, strip `"` from beginning and end and try to decode each resulting string separately.